# Converation from array of Bytes to Struct. Swift

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I have dump of bytes and i need to parse structures

c++ exmpl:

```
(*(SomeStruct*)(bufPtr))
```

how can i do it on swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of your C code would be:

```
let s = UnsafePointer<SomeStruct>(bufPtr).memory
```

(assuming `bufPtr` is of a type that `UnsafePointer` has an unnamed-argument initializer for - if not you may need another specific initializer, or to do a bit more coercion.)

Same caveats that would apply in C/C++ apply here i.e. if it turns out `bufPtr` doesn’t point to a `SomeStruct`, you’ll be sorry.

If on the other hand you want to step through the bytes one by one, you could create an `var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bufPtr)`, which can be indexed and incremented like a C pointer (i.e. `ptr[i]` and  `++ptr`).

If you know in advance how many bytes you’ve read, you can also stick it in a buffer (`let buf = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: i)`) which lets you treat it like a regular collection (use with `for-in`, `map`, `find` etc).  Again, the key is in the name – this is unsafe if you screw up the count.